# Can't ping my own local machine by IP address?

Tags: networking, ethernet, ping, traceroute

I have an Ubuntu machine named ci-server, with wired connection and fixed IP address of 192.168.0.214.

When I ping by IP I get the following output:

```
administrator@ci-server:~$ ping 192.168.0.214
PING 192.168.0.214 (192.168.0.214) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.22 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.22 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.22 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Note that it started resolving to the correct IP, but then subsequent message had a different IP.

If I do by name it resolves to localhost correctly:

```
administrator@ci-server:~$ ping ci-server
PING ci-server (127.0.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ci-server (127.0.1.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.019 ms
64 bytes from ci-server (127.0.1.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.038 ms
...
```

The `route` command gives me this:

```
administrator@ci-server:~$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

and 192.168.0.1 is the correct gateway.

I'm not sure about that second entry over there.. should that be removed?

The `traceroute` doesn't seem useful:

```
administrator@ci-server:~$ traceroute 192.168.0.214
traceroute to 192.168.0.214 (192.168.0.214), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.0.22 (192.168.0.22)  2998.079 ms !H  2997.933 ms !H  2997.921 ms !H
```

This is a VM running on VMware Workstation using bridged network. I cannot ping it from the host, and other VMs cannot ping each other. They were cloned from a template machine so they all have the same issue.

I don't know how to proceed with this. When a process (Tomcat Ant tasks) tries to reach another machine in my network by name, it fails with "java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host".

Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What makes you think that your IP is **192.168.0.214**? From the looks of it it's **192.168.0.22** ci-server just resolves to 127.0.1.1 you should always be able to ping it. Post `ifconfig -a` to be sure of IP

Comment: Damn you're right, ipconfig shows 192.168.0.22! I have configured the network using the GUI, and it seems correct there but for some reason those settings are not being used.. I'll update the question. Thanks!

Comment: On a second though, you found the issue here, so I'll mark it as Accepted and open a new question for why my settings are ignored. Thanks!